# Why isn't the designated initializer being called

Tags: ios, overriding, healthkit, designated-initializer

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6) the designated initializer should always be called, however when I try to get the blood type of user without having the permissions an `NSError` is created but its designated initializer (`- [NSError initWithDomain:code:userInfo:]`) is never called.

The code I'm using is:

```
HKHealthStore *healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
HKBloodTypeObject *bloodType = [healthStore bloodTypeWithError:&error];
NSLog(@"Blood type: %@, error: %@", bloodType, error);
```

Obs: I know that the designated initializer is not being called because I've swizzled it. Other methods like `- [NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]` behave as expected.

Why is it happening? Am I missing something? Should I open a radar?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by swizzling the NSError initializer methods?

Comment: Automatic error logging: [https://github.com/fpg1503/FPGSilentLogger](https://github.com/fpg1503/FPGSilentLogger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an error gets returned to you by a framework like HealthKit which does most of its work out of process, it's likely that the errors that get returned to you have been instantiated in another process and then delivered over XPC.  That means that the `NSError` you get in your process was actually reconstructed by `NSXPCConnection` using `NSSecureCoding`.  If you look at the `NSCoding` protocol, you'll notice that `initWithCoder:` is also a pseudo-designated initializer.  Any class that implements `NSCoding` or `NSSecureCoding` has `initWithCoder:` as an additional designated initializer which can be called instead of the other designated initializers.

Comment: Are there any other "pseudo-designated initializers"? Doesn't that destroy the point of having a designated initializer in the first place? The way I see it `initWithCoder:` is a convenience intializer created for the sole purpose of conforming to `NSCoding`, shouldn't it call `- [NSError initWithDomain:code:userInfo:]` instead of `- [NSObject init]` then?